# How much bandwidth would 2 nameservers use?

Tags: bandwidth, dns-hosting

I'm in need of 2 branded nameservers for my clients' domains. Couldn't find any information about that, but how much bandwidth and bandwidth speed would I need for those two DNS servers "just in general"? Say, I got 100 domains, some of them quite popular, some of them not at all. Can't say how much DNS queries those would "eat" because this is a total nightmare for me - counting numbers when you don't know how to count them.
Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question to answer, but here's a good starting point to look at (Assuming that you're going Windows)

> Keep in mind that for typical usage, the DNS server consumes system
>   memory as follows: Approximately 4 MB of RAM is used when the DNS
>   server is started without any zones.
>
> For each addition of zones or resource records to the server, the DNS
>   server consumes additional server memory.
>
> It is estimated that for the addition of every resource record to a
>   server zone, an average of approximately 100 bytes of server memory is
>   used.
>
> For example, if a zone containing 1000 resource records is added to a
>   server, it would require approximately 100 KB (kilobytes) of server
>   memory.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781502(v=ws.10).aspx